# Fixed broken images in email due to server assets path change

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have switched all my assets to new server; however, when someone opens an old email then previous image path link is broken.

I am trying to redirect request to old server to new one using htaccess but I am not able to do so.

What I have tried with htaccess on my old server

```
RewriteRule ^/email/images/(.*)$ http://pathtonewserver/images/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*email/images/(.*)$ http://pathtonewserver/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your htaccess is located in old server or new? It must be in old, because your images path looks like `http://oldserver/email/images/a.jpg` instead of `http://pathtonewserver/email/images/a.jpg`

Comment: its located in old server.

Comment: Is that the only content of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: no. I have other rules also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old server ,add the following Redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/email/images/(.*)/?$ http://newserver/images/$1
```

Comment: What if the OP needs to redirect `/email/images/XxX/img.jpg`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I have change the pattern to match any characters. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Its working when I open images in new tab or browser. But in email its still showing me broken image

Comment: What is the path to your images ?

Comment: www.sitename/email/images/header.png

Comment: @Starkeen Sorry my mistake my path is wrong. Its working fine. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82576/discussion-between-user1048123-and-starkeen).

Answer (score 2):

It's always good practice to turn the Rewrite Engine on before trying to use it. It might also be prudent to check that the module is installed on the server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/email/images/(.*)$ http://pathtonewserver/images/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```